# WSO2 APIM 3.0 Configuration proxy problem

Tags: proxy, wso2-api-manager

I need help for configuration WSO2APIM with proxy for backend.

**My configuration In deployment.toml**

```
[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
http.proxyHost = "myadresseproxy"
http.proxyPort = "3128"
non-blocking   = "true"
bind-address = ["localhost","myadresse"]

[transport.passthru_http.sender.parameters]
http.proxyHost = "myadresseproxy"
http.proxyPort = "3128"
non-blocking   = "true"
bind-address = ["localhost","myadresse"]
```

This configuration doesn't work :
With API need proxy i have "Error connecting to the back end"
It's ok with API didn't need pass by proxy

with this configuration the file axis2.xml is correct

What can i do ? idea ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with these configurations and it has fixed in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/pull/7115/files. You can make these changes in wso2am-3.0.0/repository/resources/conf/default.json and get this done.